# Extend call stack of failed test outside of helper function, up to the test case

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, supertest

While writing unit tests for my codebase, I've noticed that I'm duplicating the code that does the HTTP request and adds expectations for the response. So I ended up with some helper functions, one of those is called: `expectedResponseForGET`, which I made static inside a `TestUtils` class, in a file called: `utils.ts`.

In some tests I call that method multiple times to check multiple things after a POST. But when that expectation fails (the response is not what I expected to be), the test fails and the call stack shows that it failed the expectation from the `expectedResponseForGET` function, without the call stack to the test which called that helper function.

The call stack I receive for the failed expectation looks like this:

```bash
src/tests/sites/add.test.ts
  Add site route
    ✓  User4 - Add site, not company manager (238 ms)
    ✕  User1 - Add site, company manager (269 ms)

  ● Add site route ›  User1 - Add site, company manager

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  -  1
    + Received  +  1

    @@ -1,63 +1,10 @@
    -       "location": "Location2",
    +       "location": "Location",

      92 |       .set('Authorization', user.token);
      93 |     expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    > 94 |     expect(res.body).toEqual(response);
         |                      ^
      95 |     return res;
      96 |   };
      97 |

      at src/tests/utils.ts:94:22
      at fulfilled (src/tests/utils.ts:5:58)
```

This part:

```bash
at src/tests/utils.ts:94:22            -> This is for the line containing the expectation
at fulfilled (src/tests/utils.ts:5:58) -> This is for the import of request from supertest
```

Which doesn't contain the line from `src/tests/sites/add.test.ts` test file which called `expectedResponseForGET`.

Here is the test:

```
test(' User1 - Add site, company manager', async () => {
    await TestUtils.expectedResponseForPOST(
      server,
      C1.users.U1,
      route,
      C1.sites.S5.requests.addSite,
      C1.sites.S5.responses.fullSite,
    );

    await TestUtils.expectedResponseForGET(
      server,
      C1.users.U1,
      routeSites,
      C1.sites.responses.allAfterS5,
    );

   await TestUtils.expectedResponseForGET(
      server,
      C1.users.U1,
      routeWork,
      C1.work.responses.allAfterS5,
    );
  });
```

Here are the helper functions:

```
import request from 'supertest';

class TestUtils{
  static expectedResponseForGET = async (
    server: Express,
    user: UserTest,
    route: string,
    response: GenericResponse,
  ) => {
    const res = await request(server)
      .get(route)
      .set('Authorization', user.token);
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    expect(res.body).toEqual(response);
    return res;
  };

  static expectedResponseForPOST = async (
    server: Express,
    user: UserTest,
    route: string,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
    req: Object,
    response: GenericResponse,
  ) => {
    const res = await request(server)
      .post(route)
      .send(req)
      .set('Authorization', user.token);
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    expect(res.body).toEqual(response);
    return res;
  };
}
```

Has anyone encountered this problem and knows a fix for this or a workaround to display the line from the test which called the helper method?